# Disable Go To Declaration just for .SQL files in JetBrains IDEs

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rider, database-tools

Is there a way in JetBrains products to disable Go to Declaration (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>) **specifically and only for .sql files**?  I am running the latest JetBrains Rider, if that matters.

I am managing a fleet of SQL files with RedGate Flyway and editing them in Rider.  I use command line tooling to migrate my SQL scripts to a local database whenever I want to test.

To get rid of red marks, I am having Rider inspect the current state of the local DB and syntax highlight and give completions to the symbols onscreen.  Rider does a great job of this, but of course, if I <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> any highlighted symbols, I will navigate to a database object rather than source code in my project.  I am operating with muscle memory and I don't realize the switcheroo and suddenly I am merrily editing database objects that look just like my Flyway sources and I get confused when my migrations and unit tests on my local continue to fail because I'm clobbering my edits when the command line tools run, etc.

I want <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> for all other file types to work as usual, but have it disabled for SQL. Please send help.

Comment: I removed the <sql> tag since this isn't related to the SQL _language_. '_Structured Query Language (SQL) is a language for querying databases. Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data, and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used. If your question relates solely to a specific DBMS (uses specific extensions/features), use that DBMS's tag instead. Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL._'